# Parallel Lists with IndexError message

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I'm almost done with a project and can't seem to get through this section without an IndexError at the line of "max = ring[0]". If it helps, the variables ring and player are constant variables and marked as player = [] and ring = []. This is the latest Python 3 version. Thank you!

```
def main():
    player = []
    ring = []
    menu()
    addNBA(player, ring)
    rankNBA(player, ring)

# yes or no input request to continue updating ranking
def addNBA(player, ring):
    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() != 'y' and choice.lower() != "n":
        print("Invalid. Enter 'y' or 'n'.")
        playerName = playerEntry()
        player.append(playerName)
        nbaRing = ringEntry()
        ring.append(nbaRing)
        choice = input("Do you want to continue updating the ranking? Enter 'y' or 'n'. ")

# sorts list of players and rings from lowest to highest amount of rings
def rankNBA(player, ring):
    max = ring[0]
    bestPlayer = player[0]
    min = ring[0]
    worsePlayer = player[0]
    print(player)
    for i in range(len(ring)):
        print(ring[i])
        if max < ring[i]:
            max = ring[i]
            bestPlayer = player[i]
        if min > ring[i]:
            min = ring[i]
            worsePlayer = player[i]
```

Comment: What data are you passing to this method? If you get IndexError on `ring[0]` then this implies your ring data is an empty list.

Comment: I'm a new CS student so pardon me if I don't answer this correctly. rings are passed as integers and players passed as strings.

Comment: players and rings must both be lists, if you are looking to access them by index. It seems to work for me if you do e.g. `RankNBA(['a', 'b', 'c'], [0, 1, 2])`

Comment: They are both lists. This is another function I use to update the lists.

    def addNBA(player, ring):
        choice = "y"
        while choice.lower() != 'y' and choice.lower() != "n":
        print("Invalid. Enter 'y' or 'n'.")
        playerName = playerEntry()
        player.append(playerName)
        nbaRing = ringEntry()
        ring.append(nbaRing)
        choice = input("Do you want to continue updating the ranking? "
                       "Enter 'y' or 'n'. ")

Comment: Don't put code in comments - edit your question and paste it there. Also give the exact data you are entering, and the exact errors with stack traces you are seeing. The code you pasted works fine with the correct input - so it must be the input that is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Updated the question. I was wrong, those are not constant variables but are primary.

Comment: Your `while` loop is never `true` so `addNBA` runs and returns without doing anything, and then `rankNBA` is called with empty lists.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will work on addNBA and see what I can tweak.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is to ignore the error and run code.
So you should use try except statement :
Put try where you are getting error, according to your code :

```
def rankNBA(player, ring):
    try:
        max = ring[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass
    bestPlayer = player[0]
    min = ring[0]
    worsePlayer = player[0]
    print(player)
    for i in range(len(ring)):
        print(ring[i])
        if max < ring[i]:
            max = ring[i]
            bestPlayer = player[i]
        if min > ring[i]:
            min = ring[i]
            worsePlayer = player[i]
```

If same error comes again to min = ring[0] or in any other just use try except.
**Conclusion**

> We use try except statements just to tell program that it should ignore the error and move on.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm receiving the same error for bestPlayer = player(0). Do I move that line under max = ring(0) or add another except IndexError pass?

Comment: Both will do the same but try to keep everything as clean as possible so it doesn't cause you difficulty in future.

Comment: Upvote and mark question as answer so that other people can see that it is working, happy coding